# macOS Catalina drained my Macbook Pro's battery while in sleep mode

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake, power, catalina

Yesterday I updated to macOS Catalina on my Macbook Pro 13" (i7, 16GB) and something strange has happened.

Normally, the way I use the computer is to be attached to a double monitor setup, with the lid closed and with an external mouse and keyboard. The computer is always connected to the power supply (since if it weren't, I cannot use it like this with the lid closed).

When I finish my day and go to sleep, I send my computer to sleep (I use to switch it off usually once a week). With Mojave I had no problem, when I come back next day the computer is working and with the battery at 100%.

But today, when I woke up, I noticed that my computer did not begin starting, and that the battery level was 0%. It is very weird because the computer is connected all the time to the power supply and because while sleeping is very unusual to drop all the battery while sleeping.

But there is a more strange situation. I have iStat menus installed, and when I went to see how the battery was drained, my surprise is that it went from 100% to 0%.

[image: a chart with time in x axis and battery charge in y axis]

Does anybody know why could have occurred this?

Thank you.

Comment: My Macbook often reindexes the solid state drive after an update, consuming a non negligible amount of CPU power in the process. Please keep us updated on this; as in case your issue results chronic, many could want to choose to postpone upgrades. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will keep updated on this tomorrow morning or as soon as I send it to sleep again.

Comment: Today my computer acted as normal. I waked up, started it and it has plenty of battery and is working fine. I keep this post updated on any change. AS @146438 said, maybe has to be about those reindexes, but it keeps me annoyed about that step from 100% to 0% suddenly.

Comment: any change?  my pmset -g log is full "EC.RTC/Alarm Using BATT"

Comment: @goofology No. It has never occurred again, it is working properly. Sorry dude.